# Export arrays into xlsx using axlsx gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, axlsx

I'm attempting to copy all the contents of a CSV file over to an excel workbook using the AXLSX gem. On a second sheet, I only want 2 of the columns copied over. Below is an example.

I tried the '.map' method but that didn't work.

```
require 'csv'
require 'Axlsx'


p = Axlsx::Package.new
wb = p.workbook
animals = CSV.read('test.csv', headers:true)
column = ['Animals', 'Name']

headers = Array.new
headers << "Animal"
headers << "Name"
headers << "Age"
headers << "State"


wb.add_worksheet(:name => 'Copy') do |sheet|
  animals.each do |row|
    headers.map { |col| sheet.add_row [row[col]] }
  end
end


wb.add_worksheet(:name => 'Names') do |sheet|
  animals.each do |row|
    column.map { |col| sheet.add_row [row[col]] }
  end
end

p.serialize 'Animals.xlsx'
```

[CSV - But also desired output on XLSX](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9uqwT.png)
[Output from my code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/09DwV.png)

Comment: "that didn't work" is not a precise enough error description for us to help you. *What* doesn't work? *How* doesn't it work? What trouble do you have with your code? Do you get an error message? What is the error message? Is the result you are getting not the result you are expecting? What result do you expect and why, what is the result you are getting and how do the two differ? Is the behavior you are observing not the desired behavior? What is the desired behavior and why, what is the observed behavior, and in what way do they differ?

Comment: Hi Jorg, I'm very new to this so sorry for not being clear. When I used the '.map' method, it pulls the data from the CSV file into the xlsx file but only copies the data into the A column (I uploaded a screenshot titled: 'Output from my code'. The desired output is similar to my first image titled: 'CSV - But also desired output on XLSX'. Let me know I can answer anything else to help.

Comment: I think you want to do `sheet.add_row headers.map { |col| row[col] }`

Comment: @arieljuod This worked and did exactly what I was hoping it would do. Thank you for the help!

Answer (score 0):

At first read file using [`IO::readlines`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/IO.html#method-c-readlines), then split every line (separate by the cells using [`Array#map`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Array.html#method-i-map) and [`String#split`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/String.html#method-i-split)).

It will produce nested array. Something like

```
[["Animal", "Name", "Age", "State"], ["Dog", "Rufus", "7", "CA"], ["Bird", "Magnus", "3", "FL"]]
```

Each subarray here is the row of your table, each item of subarray is the cell of your table.

If you need just "Name" column on second sheet you need make nested array

```
[["Name"], ["Rufus"], ["Magnus"]]
```

That's all you need to generate XLSX file.

For example you have `animals.csv` with data serapated by `,` and want to generate `animals.xlsx`:

```
require 'axlsx'

copy = File.readlines('animals.csv', chomp: true).map { |s| s.split(',') }
names = copy.map { |l| [l[1]] }

Axlsx::Package.new do |p|
  p.workbook.add_worksheet(name: 'Animals') { |sheet| copy.each { |line| sheet.add_row(line) }}
  p.workbook.add_worksheet(name: 'Names') { |sheet| names.each { |line| sheet.add_row(line) }}
  p.serialize('animals.xlsx')
end
```